# How do I convert a scanned PDF into a PDF with text

Tags: pdf

I have scanned about 80 pages into gray scale pdf (image format).
The end size of the file is about 70MB, which is very huge.

Now I am looking for a method to convert the grayscale image-based PDF file into a simple black/white text-based PDF file.

I have done many attempts with `gs` but with no success (only a few percent recovery).
If any expert has some idea, kindly  let me know.

Comment: You need some OCR tool. Look at Tesseract http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=880471

Comment: If you're interested in keeping the PDF images as-is and adding text to it, have a look at question [Adding OCR info to a PDF](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147679/adding-ocr-info-to-a-pdf).

Comment: If you could post a link to (for example) one-page example we could test solutions...

Comment: It's not an OCR solution but http://askubuntu.com/a/3387/16395 helps a lot (although 72dpi is a bit on the low side, I have better results with 120).

Comment: Does YAGF work correct with Ubuntu 16.04? If I load an image or a pdf-document the programm aborts without any error message.
Under Ubuntu 14.04 I had no problems.
H.Roos

Answer (score 31, accepted):

gImageReader is a simple GTK+ front-end to `tesseract-ocr`.

```
sudo apt-get install gimagereader tesseract-ocr
```

[image]

*sorry for the german text*

Comment: You should also install the document's language to improve the OCR, with `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-[lang]`, replacing `lang` by the language code, like `deu` for Deutsch,  `por` for Portuguese, etc.

Comment: This software is ugly. Usability is under zero. Though it tries to do the job, but it's unable to read plain spreadsheet-like tables. Just misses the pages containing them.

Comment: This worked well for me. Just drag in the pdf, click the "Recognize all" button at the top. With a one page pdf, I waited just a few seconds, and the result appeared in a new third pane on the right hand side. The plain text in this pane can then be edited if required, and saved by clicking its "Save output" button. You can also use the mouse to highlight a particular region, and right click.

Answer (score 10):

You can try pdfocr:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/pdfocr
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install pdfocr
```

To execute the syntax is

```
 pdfocr -i input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

where `input.pdf` is the name of the input file and `output.pdf` the output file.

By default it uses Tesseract. To install it:

```
 sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

pdfocr creates an embedded text layer.

Comment: Great! Interestingly after performing the steps above the file is now searchable in Adobe Acrobat DC but not in Preview.

Comment: This repository doesn't support xenial

Comment: You can try installing an old version of pdfocr, if you install wily version on xenial it works ok.  To do this add "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu wily main" and "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu wily main" to /etc/apt/sources.list and then  "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt-get install pdfocr"

Comment: pdfocr is a script which automates the following process:

 1. Splitting the PDF file into separate pages using pdftk
 2. Extracting out the image data using pdfimages
 3. Doing OCR (optical character recognition) using cuneiform
 4. Embedding the detected text back into the PDF file using hocr2pdf
 5. Merging together the files using pdftk. (quoting from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1456756 )

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [OCRmyPDF](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that works well.

Answer (score 3):

```
pdfsandwich
```

It loads tesseract and others on install.  It's an easy one step solution and can be scripted. It can use `hocr2pdf` to create a plain text pdf, but its not ready for prime time...yet.  The default uses tesseract and creates a "sandwiched" pdf: image + text underneath.

The embedded image can be removed with commands like:

```
gs -o ocr_noIMG.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERIMAGE ocr_image.pdf
```

but the text is hidden, so it looks like a blank page.

Loading the PDF into `LibreOffice Draw` exposes the text and the image can be deleted manually.

Comment: What do we do about imagemagick / ghostscript security issues leading to `not authorized` errors in `identify-im6.q16` like this: [imagemagick - convert:not authorized `aaaa` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42928765/507544)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [shrinkpdf](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/) to reduce the filesize and then [ocr.sh](https://github.com/zgsolucoes/ocr) to add the text layer.

Answer (score 1):

For the graphical interface suggested by @A.B. on ubuntu 14.04 you should follow:

[ocr tesseract on ubuntu 14.04](https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/linux/ocr-tesseract-text-recognition-ubuntu-14-04/)

or anyway, add to the repository list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sandromani/gimagereader
sudo apt-get update
```

before this works:

```
sudo apt-get install gimagereader
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question whilst looking to convert a scanned PDF to a text-selectable PDF. I later found **pdfsandwich** which I have had very good results with and I am surprised isn't featured in detail, in the answers so far.

More information is available here: http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/

It uses the Google-sponsored *tesseract* optical character recognition library behind the scenes but simplifies the PDF processing and creation steps.

As of December 2020, it is included in the official Ubuntu repositories. To install:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install pdfsandwich
```

To process a PDF called *input.pdf*:

```
pdfsandwich input.pdf
```

By default, your output will appear as something like *input_ocr.pdf*

On Ubuntu 20.04, it didn't work initially due to a Ghostscript permissions issue. This can be worked around by adding XML comments (`<!-- xxx -->`) around out the following lines in */etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml* (in my file, these were lines 90 - 95):

```
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS2" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS3" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
```

Reference for this fix: https://www.itechlounge.net/2020/09/web-imagickexception-attempt-to-perform-an-operation-not-allowed-by-the-security-policy-pdf/

To read the documentation:

```
man pdfsandwich
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best I've found is the command `pdftotext`

`sudo apt install poppler-utils`

pretty slick and simple if you do `pdftotext -layout xxx.pdf` you even get the original layout preserved as text.

Comment: recoll uses pdftotext in it's indexing, I know not how or why.