# How do I install a new language pack for Tesseract on 16.04

Tags: language-support, ocr

Just installed gscan2pdf v1.3.9 as well as Tesseract. As for the latter, first it appeared at the bottom of my Installed Software list, but now it seems to be gone, although still working (I think).

Anyway, I'm trying to turn a pdf of a scanned document into editable text, but the document is not in English, so gscan makes a mess out of it.

Only options I get when I go to `Tools > OCR > Language to recognize` is `English`, `equ`, and `osd`. Any ideas on how I can install a specific language pack?

I'm no experienced Linux user so step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just install the necessary ocr language using this:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-[lang]
```

Where **[lang]** can be

```
all
```

OR any of the [languages listed here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html):

```
afr
amh
ara
asm
aze
aze-cyrl
bel
ben
bod
bos
bul
cat
ceb
ces
chi-sim
chi-tra
chr
cym
dan
dan-frak
deu
deu-frak
dev
dzo
ell
eng
enm
epo
est
eus
fas
fin
fra
frk
frm
gle
gle-uncial
glg
grc
guj
hat
heb
hin
hrv
hun
iku
ind
isl
ita
ita-old
jav
jpn
kan
kat
kat-old
kaz
khm
kir
kor
kur
lao
lat
lav
lit
mal
mar
mkd
mlt
msa
mya
nep
nld
nor
ori
pan
pol
por
pus
ron
rus
san
sin
slk
slk-frak
slv
spa
spa-old
sqi
srp
srp-latn
swa
swe
syr
tam
tel
tgk
tgl
tha
tir
tur
uig
ukr
urd
uzb
uzb-cyrl
vie
yid
```

This means if you want to, say, install the Norwegian version you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-nor
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day.