# gimage reader OCR

Tags: ocr

I have recently installed gimage reader OCR. It is not obvious how to use it. I have not yet worked out how to get an editable text file. My aim is to get a libreoffice file to edit and save. Thanks in advance. The original text is standard English typescript.

Answer (score 2):

#### Usage

After you loaded an image, choose "Recognize all". In the example a screenshot of your post + ocr output:

[image]

(selectable/editable-) output appears on the right.

#### N.B.

gimageReader needs one or more tesseract languages to be installed. These languages are in the repos.

Comment: I do not know the significance of 'tesseract languages', or what is meant by 'repos'.

Comment: 1. repos refers to [software sources](https://askubuntu.com/tags/software-sources/info) also called repositories.2. [How do I install a new language pack for Tesseract on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793634/how-do-i-install-a-new-language-pack-for-tesseract-on-16-04)

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I've got it to work, but on my machine gimageReader is painfully slow. I take it that Tesseract is either an alternative or will speed things up.

Comment: I've been all over the desktop, looking for 'terminal' into which I can paste a 'sudo' command. How do I find 'terminal' or 'command'? It's certainly not obvious.

Comment: @TonyB Press Ctrl + Alt + T or start gnome-terminal (assuming you are on Gnome), but where do you need the terminal in the answer?

Comment: Jacob. I have downloaded a Tesseract file [though I cannot see it in Downloads], hoping to load the Tsseract OCR facility. It involved 'sudo' so I assumed it would need a command line.

Comment: @TonyB install synaptic (GUI tool) (`sudo apt install synaptic`). then just search for tesseract, you will find a complete list of languages, just tick the ones you want to install and press "Apply".

Comment: sudo apt install synaptic prompts for sudo password. I don't remember ever setting one, but I can't find it. It does not respond to 'nul'.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence of instructions may prove useful for users:
Initiate gimageReader.
Place document in scanner: select grayscale.
Click on 'scan'. WAIT!
In the left hand panel you will see 'transferring data'.
At the same time a desktop icon will indicate that you are accumulating data for the scanned file OCRscan.png.
When the 'transferring data' phase is over, you will see an image of the scanned document in the middle of the screen. Click on 'recognize all'. WAIT!
Task bar at the bottom of the screen shows 'recognizing page' and there is a progress indicator at the right hand side of the task bar.
When the screen shows 'ready' you will see a text document in a new panel to the right of the scanned document. SAVE the text document.

Answer (score 0):

If gImageReader is very slow on your Ubuntu machine, try running it on a single thread. That worked wonderfully for me.
In a terminal, type:

```
export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1
```

If you want to check that you actually are running on one tread, type:

```
echo $OMP_THREAD_LIMIT
```

Then run gImageReader:

```
gimagereader-gtk
```

Et voilà :o)